# Check that the file XXXXX.php has been written to the 'config' directory

Tags: php, localhost

I am installing a script and in the install instruction they said:

> Check that the file global_config.php has been written to the 'config' directory. (If it hasn't, check the privileges on the config directory and run install_programo.php again).

but I don't really get what they mean. the part about checking privileges that I get. 
I did search a bit but I had no luck.

Comment: Just make sure the file exists and has stuff in it, I would assume.

Comment: ^check the file date to for extra checkingness

Comment: Are you using Windows or a *nix

Comment: I am guessing windows, or you would have fallen over privilages before, so probably all you need to do is check that the file exists

Comment: my Os is Windows and I'l using xampp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is wanting you to make sure that inside the `config` directory (folder) there is a file called `global_config.php`. If that file exists, you are good to go. If not make sure the `config` folder is writeable by doing the following:

---

### Windows:

Right Click on Folder > Properties > Uncheck the "Read Only" Checkmark > Apply > Click the "OK" button.

[image: Uncheck]
[image]

---

### Linux/Ubuntu:

`sudo chmod 775 /path/to/config`

---

### MacOS:

Open `terminal.app` and use `chmod +w /path/to/config`

---

Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: @nogad But some of us develop using it

Comment: @nogad - that's very much incorrect. I build my applications on Windows using a local server environment and then deploy them to a Linux server environment when ready for use. Saying that "no one sensible hosts on windows" is a statement that is not only false, but not constructive to helping the user find an answer at all.

Comment: Since @nogad believes no one hosts on Windows, I have updated the answer to provide the correct course of action for some OS I have experience with - hopefully these are sensible enough.

Comment: dont set the execute bit on php files

Comment: We are setting the directory to be writeable. You may want to read [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/265381/how-to-make-a-directory-permanently-writable) to learn more about what makes up Linux permission numbers.